# Passing parameters from one method to another in my controller

Tags: grails, groovy

Save parameters of a method to another.

Save parameters of the person in my def `contentPerson` in my method `saveperson`. Does anyone know how to save parameters - no found of my method `savework`

```
def saveperson(Person personIntance) {
    def contentPerson =personInstance.save(flush:true)
     redirect(controller:'Person', action:'creatework')
      flash.message="I automatically select the person id";
}

def savework(Work workInstance,contentPerson) {
    def work1 = new Work(name:params.name,person:contentPerson, profession:params.profession)
    work1.save(flush:true)
}
```

Message:

> No such property: `contentPerson`

Comment: Are you using it as a script? or class? Its because `contentPerson` is not in scope.

Comment: Where is your call to `savework()`?

Comment: May you update the post by including how you calling it ? Full stack trace?

Comment: in my PersonController

Comment: Why do you want to pass parameters from one controller method to another?

Comment: in savework method contentPerson should have a type like `def contentPerson`

Comment: please give exact stacketrace

Comment: I have to keep a parameter for loading automatic in other method i see in other view.gsp but in the same controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

redirect makes a completely new call, so it is a completely different context.
you might want to try this:

```
redirect(controller:'Person', action:'creatework', params:[contentPerson: contentPerson])
```

or save it in flash, like this:

```
flash.contentPerson = contentPerson
```

you can use it for another request, like this:

```
flash.contentPerson
```

but you should avoid flash messages. so better pass parameters.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question  use hiden