# how to pass one parameter value from admin controller to reports controller in grails

Tags: grails

i want to pass caterer value from admin controller to reports controller

getreports.gsp

```
<g:form url="[admin:catererInstance, action:'save']" >

    <div value="${adminInstance.caterer}"></div>

</g:form>
```

reportscontrooler.groovy

```
class ReportsController {


    def index() {

        redirect(action: "_getreports", params: params)

    }

    def _getreports(){

        def adminInstance=new Admin(params)

        def adminList=Admin.list().caterer


        render(template:"getreports",model:[adminInstance:adminInstance])

    }

}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644127/passing-parameters-from-one-method-to-another-in-my-controller

Comment: @Abs I don't think the question that you linked there is relevant.  That question is talking about invoking a method directly and passing parameters, standard Groovy stuff.  This question is talking about passing HTTP servlet request parameters.  They both use the term "parameter", but really are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code and simply explain how to pass value to controller from your getreports.gsp

getreports.gsp

```
<g:form url="[admin:catererInstance, action:'save']" >
 // Click SEND Button to send value to getreports action
 <g:link class="btn btn-info btn-sm" action="getreports" resource="${adminInstance}">SEND</g:link>

</g:form>
```

reportscontrooler.groovy

```
// import your admin class here.
class ReportsController {

def index() {
    redirect(action: "_getreports", params: params)
}

def _getreports(Admin adminInstance){
    // You can get your values Here.
    println "adminInstance: "+adminInstance
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You say you have two controllers, but your code shows both of your methods in `ReportsController` only. If that is the case, you should use `forward` instead of `redirect`. If you really meant to issue a redirect to `AdminController` from ReportsController, then you need to supply controller parameter in your redirect.

Although, this should do the trick, I highly suggest you not to use a `redirect` here. Better create a new service, maybe `ReportsService` and move your `_getReports()` method there. Ideally, services should be handling all your business logic, not controllers.

Comment: "You say you have two controllers, but your code shows both of your methods in ReportsController only. If that is the case, you should use forward instead of redirect" - That isn't great advice.  `redirect` and `forward` are 2 different things with different behaviors and it wouldn't matter if the involved controller actions are in the same controller or not.

Comment: I agree with you Jeff totally on that. My mistake, sorry!!